# How to use where clause for a common column across tables in union all

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have got couple of tables and all of them have a common column create_date. I have written below query to get the data and it's working fine.

```
select cola_taba, colb_taba,
  from taba
 where trunc(create_date) >= trunc(sysdate-2)
 union all
select cola_tabb, colb_tabb,
  from tabb
 where trunc(create_date) >= trunc(sysdate-2)
 union all
select cola_tabc, colb_tabc,
  from tabc
 where trunc(create_date) >= trunc(sysdate-2)
```

I am wondering if there is anyway I can do it by mentioning this column - create_date once for all tables something like below with better performance.

```
select cola_taba, colb_taba,
  from taba
 union all
select cola_tabb, colb_tabb,
  from tabb
 union all
select cola_tabc, colb_tabc,
  from tabc
 where trunc(create_date) >= trunc(sysdate-2)
```

Please let me know your thoughts on the same.

P.S. Obviously, the second query is just a non-working sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper for your union, but this will union all the data from your tables and then filters on your condition.

Your first query, filtering on each table works well with respect to the performance.

```
select * from 
(select cola_taba, colb_taba,
  from taba
 union all
select cola_tabb, colb_tabb,
  from tabb
 union all
select cola_tabc, colb_tabc,
  from tabc) T1
 where trunc(create_date) >= trunc(sysdate-2)
```

Comment: But with a wrapper, the performance will degrade as T1 will have n number of rows and out of those rows, a filter would happen out of wrapping and as you already mentioned that with my first query, performance will be better. So, still let me know if you think that performance would be better with a wrapper.

Comment: You can have index created on create_date column. But filtering on each union is the good way of making the query with performance effective

Comment: Ok thanks. However, I guess I would wait for some time for more inputs.

Comment: Not sure the performance will degrade: the optimizer may decide to move the outside WHERE clause into each part of the UNION, unless you put a hint to prevent it to do so.

Comment: @VarunJain , also remove the TRUNC around create_date. You can always write date predicate logic without resorting to using a function against the table column. Otherwise you'll throw out all use of indexes. It also causes much higher load on Exadata.

Answer (score 0):

A quick EMP type example validating that the filters are pushed to each UNION-ALL branch

```
explain plan for
select * from 
(
select * from emp1
union all
select * from emp2) t2
where hiredate > to_date( '01-01-1981', 'MM-DD-YYYY' )

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |      |    27 |  1053 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  VIEW                       |      |    28 |  1092 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                 |      |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| EMP1 |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| EMP2 |    14 |   546 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - storage("EMP1"."HIREDATE">TO_DATE(' 1981-01-01 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
       filter("EMP1"."HIREDATE">TO_DATE(' 1981-01-01 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
   4 - storage("EMP2"."HIREDATE">TO_DATE(' 1981-01-01 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
       filter("EMP2"."HIREDATE">TO_DATE(' 1981-01-01 00:00:00', 
              'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```